# VSCode + Python 3.7.6 annotation @pytest.mark.xfail undefined

Tags: python-3.x, annotations, undefined, pytest

In VSCode, I created a test_file.py and I want to write a test that I expect some error. Then I tried to put @pytest.mark.xfail. When I run the test I got "undefined" as answer.

Here is my code:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.xfail
def test_1():
    assert 2 == 1
```

Comment: Are you using pytest to run the test? Can you show the full test output?

Comment: $ pytest
= test session starts ==
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.6, pytest-5.3.5, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /Users/rayfranrochalima/git/github/cursoPython/projeto2
plugins: hypothesis-5.5.4, arraydiff-0.3, remotedata-0.3.2, openfiles-0.4.0, doctestplus-0.5.0, astropy-header-0.1.2
collected 1 item                                                                                                                        

pytest/test_cartas.py x                                                                                                           [100%]

=== 1 xfailed in 0.04s

Comment: when I run 'pytest' in terminal it is the outcome... However, when I run via VSCode, the IDE complains that the annotation @pytest.mark.xfail is undefined.

Comment: Ok, and you have selected pytest as the [test framework](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing#_enable-a-test-framework)?

Comment: Yes. I chose View > Command Pallet > Python: Configure Tests > pytest framework > folder pytest.

Comment: One further information is when I try to use the autocomplete after @pytest.mark. I don't have 'xfail' as an option, it only shows _markers and _config

Comment: After some time I could reproduce it (behaves a bit erratic). Looks like a bug to me - you could file an issue on the [VSCode site](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).

Comment: Thank you for your help and time.